# Bootstrap Modal issue in IE8 (backdrop load 10-15 times)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, modal-dialog

Look at code first.

Html button:

```
    <a href="/ajax/addrecord.php" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Add Record</a>
```

Event:

```
    $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
    $('.modal').remove(); //to remove modals if already open
    e.preventDefault();     
        $.ajax({
          url: $(this).attr('href'),              
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {$('<div class="modal hide fade" style="width:850px;">' + data + '</div>').modal()}});
});
```

In IE8 when I click on button, It loads backdrop, loads it again n again nearly 15 times but doesn't show modal. I Have put a log message in "backdrop" function in bootstrap-modal-js and for IE8 it gives more than 10 message while in other browsers log shows only 1 message.

Can anyone please give hint to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by having the full path for `href` or `data-remote`: `<a href="http://example.com/ajax/addrecord.php" ...>`